# Cheerio: select pseudo-element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="media-body">

  <div class="avatar-photo pseudo-a" tabindex="0" data-href="https://" style="background-image: url(https://6fqap94ibfgqil3r47o1.jpeg);"></div>
  <div class="media-user-reviews">
    <div class="rating-stars rating-4"><i class="fas"></i><i class="fas"></i><i class="fas"></i><i class="fas"></i><i class="far"></i></div>                        <span class="rating-mini-count">76</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `div .media-user-name` has a pseudo-element, like this:

[image: media-user-name]

The case is, that years ago I was using Xray library to parse the elements, and I take this element down, with `status: '@data-online'. But as for now, I'd like to replace it, with Cheerio. and when I am trying to:

```js
    const page = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const test = page.html('body');
    // I tried even 'div.avatar-photo.pseudo-a::active'
    const status = page(node).find('div.avatar-photo.pseudo-a');
```

Also, I have tried to use `.css('background')` or anything else to react to the element (actually I don't need the `background` itself, but it's also an option.

So, my question is, how to reach `div.avatar-photo.pseudo-a::active` (the element on screenshot)?

Because cheero gives me an error, that is doesn't support it.

Comment: i feel that, since pseudo elements are not part of DOM, they are not accessible to JS, that's why maybe it's throwing an error. even i'm interested to know more

Comment: @boxdox the funny thing is, that old-dates Xray() actually grab this by `@data-online` or something like that. But I haven't seen anywhere in HTML code this `data-online` node/selector/property/or anything else.

Comment: I think you can access by attributes, use `input[type="password"]`, so this can work, it's just pseudo elements are not present in DOM, but attributes are present on elements

Comment: @boxdox Yes, thank you so much. I have found it, seen it in the parent HTML element now. Could you please make this post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access attributes on DOM elements using the `querySelector` like this:

All password inputs: `input[type="password"]`

All div containing `data-name` tag (just an example, can be anything): `div[data-name]`

Read more about it here:

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

[a complex example [MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#a_more_complex_selector)